# Using the match operator on select statement

Tags: kdb

In kdb i have a tab:

```
tab:flip `items`sales`prices!(`nut`bolt`cam`cog;6 8 0 3;10 20 15 20)
tab
items sales prices
------------------
nut   6     10
bolt  8     20
cam   0     15
cog   3     20
```

I know I can use regex pattern matching like this:

```
select from tab where items like "cam"
```

Why can't I use the match operator the same way?:

```
select from tab where items ~ "cam"
```

This produces an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some details about how 'match(~)' and 'like' works. Maybe that will help you with your query.

**1. Match Function(~):** It compares 2 objects and returns true if they match else false.

In your example:

object1 = items list =  `nut`bolt`cam`cog

object2 = "cam"

So clearly object1 does not match with object 2.

If you want to match each item from items list to "cam" then you have to iterate over the list.

But individual item is a symbol so it will not match with object 2 which is a string.

```
   q) `cam ~ "cam" / false
```

So you need to convert either items to strings or "cam" to `cam. Here are 2 ways to do it.

```
   q) object1: `nut`cam
   q) string[object1] ~\: "cam"  / 01b
   q) object1 ~\: `cam  / 01b
```

**2. Like Function:** It is used for pattern matching and important point is if left argument is a list then it compares each item of a list with right argument instead of full list like '~' function.

Also no need to convert symbols to string as it automatically does that behind the scene.

```
   q) items: `nut`cam
   q) items like "cam"  / 01b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
q)select from tab where items ~ "cam"
```

The binary match operator is basically comparing a list of symbols vs list of chars :

```
q)`nut`bolt`cam`cog~"cam"
0b
```

since the o/p is `0b`, it does not return any record

```
select from tab where 0b
```

If you still want to use the match operator, the following should give you the correct results :

```
q)select from tab where string[items]~\:"cam"
```

Comment: Does every variable in the select statement..refer to a list?

Comment: Yes. Every column in a table is a list, regardless of the number of elements (remembering that we can have empty lists or one-element lists). You can see this in the explicit table declaration: `([]a:();b:())`